# ModuleNotFoundError when importing a Python module using the cpython crate

Tags: rust, cpython

I wrote the Rust code:

`myapp/src/main.rs`

```
extern crate cpython;

use cpython::Python;

fn main() {
    let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
    println!("Hello from Rust!");
    let py = gil.python();
    let module = cpython::PyModule::import(py, "fibo").unwrap();

    module.call(py, "fib", (1,), None).unwrap();
}
```

And saved the Python module as `myapp/pyth/fibo.py`

[image: filesystem layout]

But I get the error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: PyErr { ptype: <class 'ModuleNotFoundError'>, pvalue: Some(ModuleNotFoundError("No module named 'fibo'",)), ptraceback: None }', libcore/result.rs:945:5
```

The part of the code I'm expecting to know about the directory `pyth` is: `let module = cpython::PyModule::import(py, "fibo").unwrap();`

Comment: Which part of the code are you expecting to know about the directory `pyth`?

Comment: @Shepmaster, this part: `let module = cpython::PyModule::import(py, "fibo").unwrap();`

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I stated my question clearly. **Why** would `cpython::PyModule::import` know about the directory named `pyth`? What if you had called it `pyt` or `pytho` or `i_put_my_code_in_here`? Is `pyth` some special, hard-coded directory? If so, can you point to some documentation that describes that?

Comment: @Shepmaster,  mm, I just need it to se the module `fibo.py` so thought it may be better to put it in a separate folder, thats all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two solutions if you want to keep `fibo.py` as a separate file from your executable:

## You can add the `pyth` folder to the Python path:

```
let sys = py.import("sys")?;
PyList::downcast_from(py, sys.get("path")?)?.insert_item(py, 0, "pyth");
let module = py.import("fibo")?;
```

This assumes that the Rust executable is run from the parent folder or the project, meaning that `pyth` is a subfolder of the current path.

## Or you can import `pyth.fibo`, just like you would in Python:

```
let module = py.import("pyth.fibo")?;
```

This assumes that `pyth` is somewhere in the Python path (see first solution if you need to add the parent folder to the path).

Comment: What is the module to call: `PyList`

Comment: https://dgrunwald.github.io/rust-cpython/doc/cpython/struct.PyList.html

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

`main.rs`

```
extern crate cpython;

use cpython::{PyModule, PyResult, Python};

const FIBO_PY: &'static str = include_str!("../pyth/fibo.py");

fn main() {
    let gil = Python::acquire_gil();
    let py = gil.python();

    example(py).unwrap();
}

fn example(py: Python<'_>) -> PyResult<()> {
    let m = module_from_str(py, "fibo", FIBO_PY)?;

    let out: Vec<i32> = m.call(py, "fib", (2,), None)?.extract(py)?;
    println!(
        "successfully found fibo.py at compiletime.  Output: {:?}",
        out
    );

    Ok(())
}

/// Import a module from the given file contents.
///
/// This is a wrapper around `PyModule::new` and `Python::run` which simulates
/// the behavior of the builtin function `exec`. `name` will be used as the
/// module's `__name__`, but is not otherwise important (it does not need
/// to match the file's name).

fn module_from_str(py: Python<'_>, name: &str, source: &str) -> PyResult<PyModule> {
    let m = PyModule::new(py, name)?;

    let builtins = cpython::PyModule::import(py, "builtins").unwrap();
    m.dict(py).set_item(py, "__builtins__", &builtins).unwrap();

   // OR
    m.add(py, "__builtins__", py.import("builtins")?)?;
    let m_locals = m.get(py, "__dict__")?.extract(py)?;

    // To avoid multiple import, and to add entry to the cache in `sys.modules`.
    let sys = cpython::PyModule::import(py, "sys").unwrap();
    sys.get(py, "modules").unwrap().set_item(py, name, &m).unwrap();

    // Finally, run the moduke
    py.run(source, Some(&m_locals), None)?;
    Ok(m)
}
```

`fibo.py`

```py
def fib(n):   # return Fibonacci series up to n
    print('Hello from python!')
    result = []
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        result.append(a)
        a, b = b, a+b
    return result
```

Comment: Note that this solution will embed the Python code in your Rust executable, so that you will need to recompile the Rust executable each time the Python code changes. See my answer for solutions that keep the Python file separate.